# I want to edit the value of the data loaded by keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want my image dataset to have values in range of -1 ~ 1. 
My dataset-loading code is as following :

```
import keras_preprocessing.image as ki

ig_i1 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
ig_i2 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
ig_o1 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
ig_o2 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
ig_o3 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

ig1 = ig_i1.flow_from_directory(route+'image/',shuffle=False,class_mode=None,batch_size=bs,target_size=[128,128])
ig2 = ig_i2.flow_from_directory(route+'lv_tile/',shuffle=False,class_mode=None,batch_size=bs,target_size=[128,128])
og1 = ig_o1.flow_from_directory(route+'diffuse/',shuffle=False,class_mode=None,batch_size=bs,target_size=[128,128])
og2 = ig_o2.flow_from_directory(route+'specular/',shuffle=False,class_mode=None,batch_size=bs,target_size=[128,128])
og3 = ig_o3.flow_from_directory(route+'lambertian_shadow/',shuffle=False,class_mode=None,batch_size=bs,target_size=[128,128],color_mode='grayscale')
```

Here, I want to ig2 to have value in range from **-1 to 1**,
 but I couldn't find any method of accomplishing it.

Please teach me how to and thank you very much.

Comment: you have already rescale it `ig_i2 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)` why do you want to make it -1 to 1

Comment: Oh I mean, it rescales my image to 0~1 range. I want to make it to have negative value.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do standardization instead of normalization

```
ig_i2 = ki.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, featurewise_std_normalization=True)
```

[source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-normalize-center-and-standardize-images-with-the-imagedatagenerator-in-keras/)

Comment: Oh I want to ask some more. ig has value of 0.2~1, when it is rescaled by 1/255.0. Does the value become -0.4~1, when I applied the code you gave me ?

Comment: This is what standardize do.  It can have negative number also. Read the source link I have given you

Comment: The code you gave me says that I should pre-declare the data I will use, but my code load the data after declaring ImagedataGenerator. Is it inevitable to pre-load the dataset before declaring ImageDataGenerator ?

Comment: Actually this is something I am not sure of. It have been 2 years since I left keras and move to pytorch.